# Is it inefficient to continually call the parent model for specific data attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say on some `Child` model method I need to do calculations based on some data stored on its `Parent` model. For example,

```
def child_method(minutes)
   remaining_time = minutes % self.parent.parent_settings
   if remaining_time >= 1
       return minutes/ self.parent.parent_settings
   else
       return [minutes/self.parent.parent_settings - 1 , 0].max
   end
end
```

In the above I've called `self.parent.parent_settings` 3 times. Based on how Rails works, is this efficient? Or is it a terrible idea, and I should instead set the `parent_settings` locally, e.g.,:

```
def child_method(minutes)
   parent_settings = self.parent.parent_settings
   remaining_time = minutes % parent_settings
   if remaining_time >= 1
       return minutes/ parent_settings
   else
       return [minutes/parent_settings - 1 , 0].max
   end
end
```

I have more complex instances of this (e.g., where in one child method I'm accessing multiple parent attributes, and also in some instances, grandparent attributes). I realize the answer might be "it depends" on exactly what is the data, etc., but looking to see if there are general rules of thumb or convention

Comment: No need to put "Rails - " in your title; that's what tags are for.

Comment: What's the precise context you're asking about? I mean, if it's a reference, then any performance difference would be minimal at best. Could just time it, you know.

Comment: @DaveNewton I could time, but I'm wondering if there are established rules of thumb. One thing I"m curious about, does calling `self.parent.parent_settings` constantly reload the parent object?

Comment: As I know, rails will keep it in memory, unless you call some methods (where / count ) that will produce a database query. 
Calling self.parent.parent_settings would not constantly reload the parent object.

Comment: And you can check it in rails console, only the first time you call parent.parent_settings on a record produces a query.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, it depends.

Rails will cache fetched associations as long as the object remains in memory:

```
puts self.parent.parent_settings.object_id
# ... Some code
puts self.parent.parent_settings.object_id # => This should be the same object ID as before
```

This cache is cleared automatically by the framework and can be explicitly cleared via `#reload`:

```
self.reload
```

Your code should be fine as long as you're not running `child_method` multiple times in a request/response cycle. Even if you do run `child_method` multiple times in the same request/response cycle, there's another database query cache that will intercept the same DB queries. The db query cache is only active when in production mode or when a special ENV var is set.